# how to use single platform device driver for multiple devices

Tags: linux-device-driver, procfs

I have 3 devices which are working in the similar way. I have a driver designed for one of the devices. I have added compatibility with

```
.compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-0.00.a"
.compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-1.00.a" and
.compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-2.00.a"
```

It probes only the last device "xyz,hmcSPI-2.00.a" but first and second are seems to be disconnected. Meaning when I send data to the driver in /proc/hmcSPI0 then it reflects on only last device but not on first and second. When I remove third device "xyz,hmcSPI-2.00.a" from the device tree and driver then it detect "xyz,hmcSPI-1.00.a" but not "xyz,hmcSPI-0.00.a". Also, it shows probing physical address of the last device. I want to use this single driver for all three devices which are having different addresses.
Following is my platform driver.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>    /* Needed for copy_from_user */
#include <asm/io.h>         /* Needed for IO Read/Write Functions */
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>  /* Needed for Proc File System Functions */
#include <linux/seq_file.h> /* Needed for Sequence File Operations */
#include <linux/platform_device.h>  /* Needed for Platform Driver    Functions */
#include<linux/slab.h>   
/* Define Driver Name */
#define DRIVER_NAME "hmcSPI0"


unsigned long *base_addr;   /* Vitual Base Address */
struct resource *res;       /* Device Resource Structure */
unsigned long remap_size;   /* Device Memory Size */
u16 slave_reg_add=0;
char hmcSPI0_phrase[16];





/* Write operation for /proc/hmcSPI0
 * -----------------------------------
 *  When user cat a string to /proc/hmcSPI0 file, the string will be stored in
 *  const char __user *buf. This function will copy the string from user
 *  space into kernel space, and change it to an unsigned long value.
 *  It will then write the value to the register of hmcSPI0 controller.
 */

 static ssize_t proc_hmcSPI0_write(struct file *file, const char __user * buf,
              size_t count, loff_t * ppos)
  {
  
  u32 hmcSPI0_value;
                                                            

if (count < 14) {
        if (copy_from_user(hmcSPI0_phrase, buf, count))
            return -EFAULT;

    hmcSPI0_phrase[count] = '\0';
    slave_reg_add=hmcSPI0_phrase[2]; //Copy first hex number which is offset to variable
    hmcSPI0_phrase[2]=48;       //Replace it by zero
 
if (slave_reg_add>=48){     //48='0' ASCII
    slave_reg_add=(slave_reg_add-48);   // //Convert the ACSII chr to Decimal Number
    
        if(slave_reg_add<15){
         hmcSPI0_value = simple_strtoul(hmcSPI0_phrase, NULL, 0);
         wmb();
         iowrite32(0x0, (base_addr+2)); //Clear Done slave reg2
         iowrite32(hmcSPI0_value, (base_addr+slave_reg_add));
        if(slave_reg_add == 0){
            if((hmcSPI0_phrase[3]-48)==4)
                iowrite32(0x4, (base_addr));
            else if ((hmcSPI0_phrase[3]-48)==1 || (hmcSPI0_phrase[3]-48)==3){
            while (ioread32((base_addr+2)) == 0);//wait untill transfer of all data
                iowrite32(0x0, (base_addr+2));//Clear Done slave reg2
            iowrite32(0x0, (base_addr));
            }
            else{}
        }           
    
    }else {
            slave_reg_add=hmcSPI0_phrase[3];
        slave_reg_add=(slave_reg_add-48);
    }
 }
     }
 
 return count;
 }
 
 /* Callback function when opening file /proc/hmcSPI0
  * ------------------------------------------------------
  *  Read the register value of hmcSPI0 controller, print the value to
  *  the sequence file struct seq_file *p. In file open operation for /proc/hmcSPI0
  *  this callback function will be called first to fill up the seq_file,
  *  and seq_read function will print whatever in seq_file to the terminal.
  */
 static int proc_hmcSPI0_show(struct seq_file *p, void *v)
 {
     u32 hmcSPI0_value;
     slave_reg_add=3;                                                                        
     hmcSPI0_value = ioread32((base_addr+slave_reg_add));
     seq_printf(p, "Slave Reg=0x%x , Data=0x%x \n", slave_reg_add,hmcSPI0_value);
     return 0;
 }
 
 /* Open function for /proc/hmcSPI0
   * ------------------------------------
   *  When user want to read /proc/hmcSPI0 (i.e. cat /proc/hmcSPI0), the open function 
   *  will be called first. In the open function, a seq_file will be prepared and the modprobe chdir no such file or directory zynq
   *  status of hmcSPI0 will be filled into the seq_file by proc_hmcSPI0_show function.
   */
 static int proc_hmcSPI0_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
  {
      unsigned int size = 16;
      char *buf;
      struct seq_file *m;
      int res;
  
      buf = (char *)kmalloc(size * sizeof(char), GFP_KERNEL);
      if (!buf)
          return -ENOMEM;
  
      res = single_open(file, proc_hmcSPI0_show, NULL);
  
      if (!res) {
          m = file->private_data;
          m->buf = buf;
          m->size = size;
      } else {
          kfree(buf);
      }
  
      return res;
  }
  
  /* File Operations for /proc/hmcSPI0 */
  static const struct file_operations proc_hmcSPI0_operations = {
      .open = proc_hmcSPI0_open,
      .read = seq_read,
      .write = proc_hmcSPI0_write,
      .llseek = seq_lseek,
      .release = single_release
  };
  
  /* Shutdown function for hmcSPI0
   * -----------------------------------
   *  Before hmcSPI0 shutdown, clear the data
  */
 static void hmcSPI0_shutdown(struct platform_device *pdev)
 {
    iowrite32(0, base_addr);
 }
 
 /* Remove function for hmcSPI0
  * ----------------------------------
  *  When hmcSPI0 module is removed, clear all data first,
  *  release virtual address and the memory region requested.
  */
 static int hmcSPI0_remove(struct platform_device *pdev)
 {
     hmcSPI0_shutdown(pdev);
 
     /* Remove /proc/hmcSPI0 entry */
     remove_proc_entry(DRIVER_NAME, NULL);
 
     /* Release mapped virtual address */
     iounmap(base_addr);
 
     /* Release the region */
     release_mem_region(res->start, remap_size);
 
     return 0;
 }
 
 /* Device Probe function for hmcSPI0
  * ------------------------------------
  *  Get the resource structure from the information in device tree.
  *  request the memory regioon needed for the controller, and map it into
  *  kernel virtual memory space. Create an entry under /proc file system
  *  and register file operations for that entry.
  */
 static int hmcSPI0_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
 {
     struct proc_dir_entry *hmcSPI0_proc_entry;
     int ret = 0;
 
     res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);
     if (!res) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "No memory resource\n");
         return -ENODEV;
     }
 
     remap_size = res->end - res->start + 1;
     if (!request_mem_region(res->start, remap_size, pdev->name)) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Cannot request IO\n");
         return -ENXIO;
     }
 
     base_addr = ioremap(res->start, remap_size);
     if (base_addr == NULL) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Couldn't ioremap memory at 0x%08lx\n",
             (unsigned long)res->start);
         ret = -ENOMEM;
         goto err_release_region;
     }

     hmcSPI0_proc_entry = proc_create(DRIVER_NAME, 0, NULL,
                        &proc_hmcSPI0_operations);
     if (hmcSPI0_proc_entry == NULL) {
         dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Couldn't create proc entry\n");
         ret = -ENOMEM;
         goto err_create_proc_entry;
     }
 
     printk(KERN_INFO DRIVER_NAME " probed at VA 0x%08lx\n",
            (unsigned long) base_addr);
     printk(KERN_INFO DRIVER_NAME " probed at PA 0x%08lx\n",
        (unsigned long)res->start);
 
     return 0;
 
  err_create_proc_entry:
     iounmap(base_addr);
  err_release_region:
     release_mem_region(res->start, remap_size);
 
     return ret;
 }
 
 /* device match table to match with device node in device tree */
 static const struct of_device_id hmcSPI0_of_match[] = {
     {.compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-0.00.a"},
     {.compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-1.00.a"},
     {.compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-2.00.a"},
     {},
 };
 
 MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, hmcSPI0_of_match);
 
 /* platform driver structure for hmcSPI0 driver */
 static struct platform_driver hmcSPI0_driver = {
     .driver = {
            .name = DRIVER_NAME,
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
            .of_match_table = hmcSPI0_of_match},
     .probe = hmcSPI0_probe,
     .remove = hmcSPI0_remove,
     .shutdown = hmcSPI0_shutdown
};

 /* Register hmcSPI0 platform driver */
 module_platform_driver(hmcSPI0_driver);

 /* Module Informations */
 MODULE_AUTHOR("Ganesh Kalbhor, xyz.");
 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
 MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_NAME ": hmcSPI0 driver (Simple Version)");
 MODULE_ALIAS(DRIVER_NAME);
```

device tree entry is as follows

```
/ {
    model = "Zynq Zed Development Board";
    compatible = "xlnx,zynq-zed", "xlnx,zynq-7000";

    aliases {
        ethernet0 = &gem0;
        serial0 = &uart1;
        spi0 = &qspi;
    };

    memory {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x0 0x20000000>;
    };

    chosen {
        bootargs =  "console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/ram rw earlyprintk";
        linux,stdout-path = &uart1;
        stdout-path = &uart1;
    };

    usb_phy0: phy0 {
        compatible = "usb-nop-xceiv";
        #phy-cells = <0>;
    };

    hmcSPI0 {
        compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-0.00.a";
        reg = <0x43C00000 0x1000>;
    };

    hmcSPI0 {
        compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-1.00.a";
        reg = <0x43C10000 0x1000>;
    };

    hmcSPI0 {
        compatible = "xyz,hmcSPI-2.00.a";
        reg = <0x43C20000 0x1000>;
    };

};
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Shouldn't be different descriptions for hmcSPIX? What are you trying to connect? Are they SPI slave devices or SPI hosts? Why can't you use the one compatible string for all?

Comment: This is SPI master (host) device. I am trying to send the same data on different SPI master devices which are using addresses 0x43C00000, 0x43C10000 and 0x43C20000 (like USB driver, where one driver is used for multiple devices simultaneously). Yes I can use same compatible string but its not solving the problem I have tried with that.